# Yii Rights - Case Insensitive

Tags: yii

In the Yii Rights extension, how do I make it ignore case when it's setting the user's rights?

For example: I have an user named admin in the tbl_users. If I login with admin, the user will get the rights set in the AuthAssignment table. However, if I login as ADMIN, it will not set the user's rights correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Well i think case sensitivity is important for data integrity and cant be turned off like a switch.

But there is a way around it-

When you login use `strtolower()` to convert to small case.

I hope it solves your problem.

Cheers.